# How can i add an json into an index on my json

Tags: javascript, json, push

I'm trying to insert some more data into an json I'm retrieving from an database, I need to insert it into an already existing json index.

I've already tried to do an `json[0].push(otherjson)`, but I don't understand how to do this.

```
var devices = JSON.parse(result);

//devices = [{ {id:1, name:'device1'},{id:2, name:'device2'} }]

devices[0].push({"data1":{"temp":"100", "humid":"12"}});
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the commented devices is correct JSON, as they always need to have key-value pairs for objects. So `{object, object}` is incorrect, `[object, object]` is, and `{0:object, 1:object}` would be as well. Can you log the devices somehow so we can see the proper structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var devices = [  {id:1, name:'device1'}, {id:2, name:'device2'} ];
devices[0]['data1'] = [{"temp":"100", "humid":"12"}];
```

Comment: I'm glad. Kindly approve my answer so as to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can push new elements into an array. Note that devices[0] is not an array rather it's an object.
And you can add new key and corresponding values into an object in this way
object.new_key = new_value
hence your code will be `devices[0]."data1" = [{"temp":"100", "humid":"12"}];`